# Output is invalid

Tags: c#, php, encryption, rijndaelmanaged, rijndael

I have a PHP program that encrypts a PDF file into .xxx file this output is being read by a C# program that decrypts this .xxx file back into PDF file.

My problem is that when I open the file decrypted by C# , the PDF reader tells me that the file is corrupted .. when I encrypt plain text in PHP and decrypt on C# I got the file I encrypted .. so the problem is appearing only in PDF files or in other words it appears in **BINARY** files

any suggestions ?!

Notes:

1. In PHP I use mcrypt extension Rijndael algorithm CBC PKCS7 padding (padding is done manually)
2. In C# I use RijndaelManaged class to encrypt and decrypt data

**Edit**:

Here is encryption method that I use in PHP:

```
    function encrypt($key, $iv, $text) {
        ini_set ( 'memory_limit', '-1' );
        $mcrypt_cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
        $mcrypt_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
        $text=addpadding($text,mcrypt_get_block_size($mcrypt_cipher,'cbc'));
        $encrypted = rtrim ( mcrypt_encrypt ( $mcrypt_cipher, $key, $text, $mcrypt_mode, $iv ), "\0" );
        $encrypted = base64_encode ( $encrypted );
        return $encrypted;
    }
```

And here is the decryption method in C#:

```
    public static string DecryptString(string message, string KeyString, string IVString)
    {
        byte[] Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString);
        byte[] IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IVString);

        string decrypted = null;
        RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();
        rj.BlockSize = 256;
        rj.Key = Key;
        rj.IV = IV;
        rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            //Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] messageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                //byte[] messageBytes = enc.GetBytes(message);

                cs.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            byte[] encoded = ms.ToArray();
            decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);

            ms.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred:"+ e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            rj.Clear();
        }

        return decrypted;
    }
```

and here is how I call the decrypt in C# and how I write output:

```
                string Key = cryptography.MD5("X-Ware" + cryptography.MD5("123"));
                string IV = cryptography.MD5("XWare");
                string decrypted = cryptography.DecryptString(contents, Key, IV);
                string outputFilename = cryptography.MD5(OFD.FileName) + ".tmp";

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\" + outputFilename, false, Encoding.UTF8);
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(sw.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                //sw.Write(decrypted);
                bw.Write(decrypted);
                sw.Close();
                bw.Close();
```

Comment: Can you paste how you do the encoding/decoding?

Comment: Does the decrypted file have the same file size as the original one?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes on Windows .......

Comment: @Bandpay In fact no ... decrypted is larger than original

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is in `fopen`, do you use `'rb'`?

Comment: Can you decrypt it in PHP :)?

Comment: @greut I open the PDF in PHP using fopen 'rb' :)

Comment: @Bandpay yes I can decrypt in PHP which makes me feel like this is encoding problem

Comment: I know not much about C#. I was thinking if you could compare the original file and the decrypted one by some file comparison software. See if you spot some clues. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you treat the binary PDF data as text on both the PHP and the C# side.

```
 decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);
```

makes no sense if `encoded` represents binary data. You should probably skip this step and define your `DecryptString()` as returning `byte[]`. And then rename it too.

If you do want it as a string you might have better luck with ASCII or ANSI encoding:

```
 decrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encoded);
```

but the error may already be happening on the PHP side, I can't tell.

Additional, I just noted:

```
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\" + outputFilename,  
           false, Encoding.UTF8);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(sw.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

This is a very over-complicated way to create a BinaryWriter. The Encoding will not be used. And

```
 bw.Write(decrypted);
```

This will write the string with a length-prefix, that certainly will make your PDF invalid.

When you keep the return of Decrypt as `string`, use

```
  File.WriteAllText("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\" + outputFilename, decrypted);
```

And when you return it as `byte[]` (recommended), use

```
 File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\" + outputFilename, decrypted);
```

Comment: Also, although I'm not sure about this without reading all the documentation on the methods, it would seem the data is padded in php but never "unpadded" in C#.

Comment: @Joachim: The OP states that the process works for text data, that makes me think the default padding settings are OK.

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely not sure it's a problem, but it's something I'd watch in the end that the files were identical size :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you very much it is working fine now bye editing the code to return byte array not a string

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I built a padding method in PHP to be compatible with C# padding mode =PKCS#7